# Having trouble getting CMake to work with third party libraries

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to make a small game using both SFML and Box2D. I have the following directory structure:

```
/
    src/
        game/ # my code
        thirdparty/ # other libraries' code
            box2d/
            sfml/
    bin/
    etc...
```

I'm trying to set it up so that I can run make and have box2d or sfml compile as well if they need, since I might make some changes to the libraries.

I've tried putting this in my CMkaeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Box2D)
find_package(sfml-window)
find_package(sfml-graphics)
find_package(sfml-system)
```

as well as other things, but I keep getting errors and I'm not sure how to get around them. for example:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package):
  Could not find module Findsfml-window.cmake or a configuration file for
  package sfml-window.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find Findsfml-window.cmake or set
  sfml-window_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  sfml-window.  The file will have one of the following names:

    sfml-windowConfig.cmake
    sfml-window-config.cmake
```

But I can't find any of the files it lists there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The find_pacakge command is for finding packages that are defined in for cmake as modules or configurations.  There is probably not a cmake module or config defined for these libraries. So, if you want to use the find package command to find these libraries then you will need to create a cmake module that knows how to find them.  Given your stated requirements I would not think that this is easiest way to do it.

If you are statically linking you libraries then set up a custom target to invoke make on each of the libraries.  Add the include directories to your include path.  Use find_library command to find the libraries.

If you intend to dynamically link your libraries then create a custom target to build and install your libraries and you should be good as long as you install them in one of the normal places.

Comment: Could you possibly post a simple example of how to do these things? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Have a gander here:

http://www.itk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries Writing find modules

Take a look at the "Writing find modules" section.  Be sure to read the document all the way through.

If you want to make redistributable and portable cmake projects, I think this is the right direction for you to go.